# AppBar Button Changing icon dynamically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, appbar

I have a button on appBar. When user clicks it, it should change the icon. It will either show the Map or List so it needs to toggle between those 2.
If I use the code below with icons Symbol.Play & Symbol.Stop it toggles perfectly.
But when I use Symbol.Map & Symbol.List it does not toggle properly. (On simulator at least.) It changes sometimes, but mostly stays the same icon.

Code:

```
private void MapToggle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (JobMap.Visibility != Visibility.Visible)
        {
            MapToggle.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.List);
            MapToggle.Label = "List";
            JobMap.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            MapToggle.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Map);
            MapToggle.Label = "Map";
            JobMap.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

Binded to XAML

```
AppBarButton Name="MapToggle" Icon="Map" Click="MapToggle_Click" Label="Map"
```

Comment: why don't you have two buttons conditionally shown by JobMap.Visibility != Visibility.Visible?

Comment: that would be an ugly solution. There is other buttons in the app bar too. It might not look good.

Comment: other option is to bind the Icon property to what you want. for example to a enumerator and then use a converter to transform to "new simbolicon" ...

Comment: @sexta13 I tried that too. Same. Works with Play/Pause not with Map/List